# Is there a standard library function for binary search on a sorted list in Dart?

Tags: dart, binary-search

Is there a standard library method for binary search on a sorted list in Dart?

I've Googled and there seems [to be one in flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/binarySearch.html), but I can't find one in dart.

I also found [this bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/issues/9) which mentions `lowerBound()` and binary search. It appears there used to be a [collections/algorithms package](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart.pkg.collection.algorithms/dart.pkg.collection.algorithms-library.html) but this appears deprecated and I can't see a replacement in `collections.dart`.

It isn't difficult to write one but I prefer to use standard library methods if possible.

Answer (score 7):

The methods are there in the [collection.dart](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/collection-library.html) package.

They can be a little hard to spot. If you scroll down they are in the `Functions` section and there is both [`binarySearch()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/binarySearch.html) and [`lowerBound()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/lowerBound.html)

It's important to notice this is `package:collection`, not `dart:collection` which also exists. But both are written by the Dart developers.

To import it use:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```